# fuzzywuzzy is showing class Diff_SequenceMatcher not found

Tags: php, phalcon, fuzzywuzzy

When I am extending SequenceMatcher class with Diff_SequenceMatcher which is written in PHP using Phalcon. it is showing that, class not found in fuzzywuzzy?

Comment: Are you mixing PHP and Python? How are you doing that? In general, a PHP library cannot call a Python one, and vice versa.

Comment: i am using like a component

Comment: Try running it in pure php first. I don't see any `Diff_SequenceMatcher` class in https://github.com/wyndow/fuzzywuzzy component

Comment: you can see it in Diff folder

Comment: You're right. Note that it has a namespace: `namespace Gowili\FuzzyWuzzy\Diff;` Did you use it's full path when you called it?

Comment: yes, i have used it. i solved problem by changing class name and file name. Thank you very much and thanks a lot for helping.